# Unable to query hive tables from spark

Tags: hive, apache-spark

I want to create/access the hive tables from spark.

I have placed the hive-site.xml inside the spark/conf directory. Even though it creates a local metastore in the directory where I run the spark shell and exists with an error.

I am getting this error when I try to create a new hive table.

sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING)")

Please suggest a way to resolve this

```
15/02/12 10:35:58 ERROR RetryingHMSHandler: MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/src is not a directory or unable to create one)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:1294)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Comment: A couple of things you might try.  1) make sure hadoop is started.  `start-all.sh` and `jps` to confirm.  2)  You might need to create a database first.  Spark doesn't like the default db.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem, and solved it as follows:

1. add the hive conf directory to spark-env.sh
   SPARK_CLASSPATH=/opt/apache-hive-0.13.1-bin/conf
2. edit hdfs-site in hive conf directory by adding "hdfs://master:8020" to hive.metastore.warehouse.dir. For example : hdfs://master:8020/user/hive/warehouse

Comment: This worked for me!! Thanks a lot! I was actually using sparkSQL and it was setting this property to its default value which is 'file:/user/hive/warehouse'. But my user of course did not have rights to this directory. So I included a java property in spark's script while starting it: -Dhive.metastore.warehouse.dir=hdfs://hdfs_master_ip:hdfs_port/user/hive/warehouse

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar error while running Spark SQL on hive, and it turned out that the running user (of mac) for Spark SQL does not have write permission to mac directory /user/hive/warehouse, which Spark/Hive was trying to create somehow (not sure why though, since my metastore is on mysql, and data file in hdfs).
The error was gone after I use "sudo" to start Spark shell, i.e.,

bin> sudo ./spark-shell